# Find files containing a given text

Tags: bash, find

In bash I want to return file name (and the path to the file) for every file of type `.php|.html|.js` containing the case-insensitive string `"document.cookie" | "setcookie"`

How would I do that?

Comment: Have you considered just using grep? http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grep-in-bash/

Comment: This title is fairly misleading. "find-files-containing-a-given-text"

Answer (score 262, accepted):

```
egrep -ir --include=*.{php,html,js} "(document.cookie|setcookie)" .
```

The `r` flag means to search recursively (search subdirectories). The `i` flag means case insensitive.

If you just want file names add the `l` (lowercase `L`) flag:

```
egrep -lir --include=*.{php,html,js} "(document.cookie|setcookie)" .
```

Comment: that didn't seem to work for me(at least not on mac)....just hangs... egrep -lir --include=* "repo"
egrep: warning: recursive search of stdin

Comment: You forgot to add the path to search. The path is '.' in the above example. In your case, the script is waiting for the input to search on stdin. Try: egrep -lir --include=* "repo" / (or any other path)

Comment: `grep -E ... ` > `egrep ...`

Comment: I got error `grep: (error|fail): No such file or directory` on Ubuntu Desktop 16; any hints?

Comment: For me to make this working, I had to skip the * with \. so I have `--include=\*.{php,html,js}`

Comment: Mask didn worked for me there as above: grep -lir --include=*.{php} "mongo" . , my solution: grep -lir --include="*.php" "mongo" .

Comment: On Mac:  egrep -ir --include=\\*.{php,html,js} "(document.cookie|setcookie)" .

Comment: Several of the previous commenters have actually pointed to the same issue with grep vs egrep. As @Aman has mentioned above, egrep is same as 'grep -E'. With grep, '*' does not need to be escaped but the '|' does, and with egrep, it's the opposit.

Answer (score 74):

Try something like `grep -r -n -i --include="*.html *.php *.js" searchstrinhere .`

the `-i` makes it case insensitlve

the `.` at the end means you want to start from your current directory, this could be substituted with any directory.

the `-r` means do this recursively, right down the directory tree

the `-n` prints the line number for matches.

the `--include` lets you add file names, extensions. Wildcards accepted

For more info see: http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/

Comment: Or perhaps use the `-l` option (just print filenames that match) instead of `-n`

Answer (score 19):

`find` them and `grep` for the string:

This will find all files of your 3 types in /starting/path and grep for the regular expression `'(document\.cookie|setcookie)'`.  Split over 2 lines with the backslash just for readability...

```
find /starting/path -type f -name "*.php" -o -name "*.html" -o -name "*.js" | \
 xargs egrep -i '(document\.cookie|setcookie)'
```

Comment: Like universal usage of find, but to my mind better to use `-exec grep -l 'sth' {} \;`

Comment: Thanks @Michael Berkowski This way fastest more than 5 or 8 times `# egrep -ir --include=file.foo "(foo|bar)" /dir` on ~500Gb weigth directory.

Answer (score 14):

Sounds like a perfect job for `grep` or perhaps [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/)

Or this wonderful construction:

```
find . -type f \( -name *.php -o -name *.html -o -name *.js \) -exec grep "document.cookie\|setcookie" /dev/null {} \;
```

Comment: +1 Using `-exec grep...` is better than my `xargs` method because it won't choke on spaces in filenames.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski : You can use it like this to deal with whitespace in filenames: `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} grep "search_string" {}`. Of course, the other options can be added as well.

Answer (score 5):

```
find . -type f -name '*php' -o -name '*js' -o -name '*html' |\
xargs grep -liE 'document\.cookie|setcookie'
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to include one more alternative, you could also use this:

`find "/starting/path" -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex "^.*\.(php|html|js)$" -exec grep -EH '(document\.cookie|setcookie)' {} \;`

Where:

- `-regextype posix-extended` tells `find` what kind of regex to expect
- `-regex "^.*\.(php|html|js)$"` tells `find` the regex itself filenames must match
- `-exec grep -EH '(document\.cookie|setcookie)' {} \;` tells `find` to run the command (with its options and arguments) specified between the `-exec` option and the `\;` for each file it finds, where `{}` represents where the file path goes in this command.

  while

  - `E` option tells `grep` to use extended regex (to support the parentheses) and...
  - `H` option tells `grep` to print file paths before the matches.

And, given this, if you only want file paths, you may use:

`find "/starting/path" -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex "^.*\.(php|html|js)$" -exec grep -EH '(document\.cookie|setcookie)' {} \; | sed -r 's/(^.*):.*$/\1/' | sort -u`

Where

- `|` [pipe] send the output of `find` to the next command after this (which is `sed`, then `sort`)
- `r` option tells `sed` to use extended regex.
- `s/HI/BYE/` tells `sed` to replace every First occurrence (per line) of "HI" with "BYE" and...
- `s/(^.*):.*$/\1/` tells it to replace the regex `(^.*):.*$` (meaning a **group** [stuff enclosed by `()`] including *everything* [`.*` = one or more of any-character] from *the beginning of the line* [`^`] till' the first ':' followed by *anything* till' the *end of line* [`$`]) by the first **group** [`\1`] of the replaced regex.
- `u` tells sort to remove duplicate entries (take `sort -u` as optional).

...FAR from being the most elegant way. As I said, my intention is to increase the range of possibilities (and also to give more complete explanations on some tools you could use).