# Get files which contains a specific text using Linux

Tags: linux, shell, grep, find

I want to find files in Linux, in a specific directory **without looking into its subdirectories**, which contains in their text a specific string. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16957078/2037229) answer, I tried this after removing the `r` of recursion:

```
grep -nw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e "pattern"
```

But it not working. I tried also this with skipping directory optin:

```
grep -rnw -d skip '/path/to/somewhere/' -e "pattern"
```

I tried to exclude any directory that is different from the current directory, but also no way:

```
grep -rnw -exclude-dir '[^.]' '../../path/to/somewhere/' -e "pattern"
```

Comment: `find . -type f -name '*pattern*'`

Comment: These will look into all files in the path for `pattern` I guess that is not what you are trying to do. `find` or `ls ... | grep` will be helpful

Comment: if you still want to use grep try `grep /path/to/somewhere/*  -d skip -le "pattern"`

Comment: May be the question was confusing, i hope its clear now, the patten should match the content not the filename !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash script - find file containing text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153152/bash-script-find-file-containing-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> May be the question was confusing, i hope its clear now, the patten should match the content not the filename !

Your question was not clear, and in the original answer I have shown how to find *filenames* matching a pattern. If you only want to search for files with content matching a pattern, it's as simple as

```
grep 'pattern' directory/*
```

(the shell globbing is used).

You can still use `find` to filter out the files before passing to `grep`:

```
find 'directory' -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f \
  -exec grep --with-filename 'pattern' {} +
```

## Original Answer

Grep is not appropriate tool for searching for filenames, since you need to generate a list of files before passing to Grep. Even if you get the desired results with a command like `ls | grep pattern`, you will have to append another pipe in order to process the files (I guess, you will most likely need to process them somehow, sooner or later).

Use `find` instead, as it has its own powerful pattern matching features.

Example:

```
find 'directory' -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -regex '.*pattern'
```

Use `-iregex` for case insensitive version of `-regex`. Also read about `-name`, `-iname`, `-path`, and `-ipath` options.

---

It is possible to run a command (or script) for the files being processed with `-exec` action, e.g.:

```
find 'directory' -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f \
  -regex '.*pattern' -exec sed -i.bak -r 's/\btwo\b/2/g' {} +
```

Comment: Yeah, `grep 'pattern' *` is more than enough.

Comment: Although it shows error for subdirectories, but its acceptable answer, thx man !

Answer (score 1):

Using `find`:

```
find '/path/to/somewhere' -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep -H 'pattern' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern must be a regular expression:

```
ls -A /path/to/dir | grep -E PATTERN
```