# How I can search codeline into opencart files for a change grid view in category page OpenCart 2.3

Tags: opencart

I was looking this codeline `col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-one-two 0` in all opencart files with template files (PHPStorm, Total Commander), but I don't know where is codeline can be. This codeline for me need for a change grid view for category page.
How I can search this codeline?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find files containing a given text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153152/find-files-containing-a-given-text)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot find given codeline with fulltextsearch, because in OpenCart these classes are assembled by PHP in page .tpl files.

Please take in mind, that any plugin can also modify classes of any container either by PHP or by JavaScript.

File, you are searching for, and is responsible for displaying category page, is located in */catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/category.tpl*

Comment: Is any chance that you are using third-party template? Also, please make sure you are using OpenCart version 2.3. Could you please post structure of your /catalog/view/theme/ folder?

Comment: 1. Yes I using MyShop template by TonyTemplates (now is not supported)                  2. Structure: assents
default
myshop
header_v1.php
header_v2.php
header_v3.php
header_v4.php
header_v5.php
header_v6.php
header_v7.php
header_v8.php
header_v9.php
module_list.php
module_list_v.php

Comment: If these are all files, that you have in theme view folder, then template is developed out-of OpenCart standarts and in this case you should ask developer of template for support.