# How to use the grep with globs patterns? (like we use it in find command)

Tags: linux, grep

Let's see if we want to find all file name as below format

```
gstreamer_abc.c
gstreamer_xyz.c
gstreamer_abcxyz.c
```

then we can use find command as below

```
find ./ -iname "gstreamer_*.c"
```

Same way i need to grep some APIs in file as below

```
gstABCNode()
gstAnythingCanBeHereNode()
gstXyzNode()
```

I am trying something

```
grep -rni "gst*Node"  ./
grep -rni "gst^\*Node" ./
```

But it does not gives what i need here. First is it possible to search with grep like this or if possible then how to grep such pattern?

Comment: `find . -type f -exec grep -rni pattern {} /dev/null \;`  (or use -H)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find files containing a given text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153152/find-files-containing-a-given-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `find` uses "globs" while `grep` uses regular expressions. With `find`, `*` means "a string of any length". With `grep`, `*` means "any number of times the element (character) that precedes". This way, your command:

```
grep -rni "gst*Node"  ./
```

searches for any string that starts with `gs`, any number of times `t`, and `Node` (which is presumably not what you want). Try rather:

```
grep -rni "gst.*Node"  ./
```

The `.` means "any character", so `.*` really means "a string of any length".

Comment: What about `{ts,js,tsx,jsx}` I can't rewrite it to `(ts|js|tsx|jsx)`, because under windows `|` is always interpreted as special character. I would really like to use globs with grep. /edit Ok, this works `grep -e '.ts$' -e '.tsx$'`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can `grep` only these files:

```
grep --include "gstreamer_*.c" -rni "gst*Node"  ./
```